# How to plot different indices keeping one fixed in R

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have a data frame with house price indices (sales and rents) with 3 different versions of the HPI and the median price index. So,  I have a variable "Value" with the value of the index, "Index" with either HPI1, HPI2, HPI3 or Median, for the type of index, "Operation" for sale or rent and Month. It looks something like this, but for a longer period of time.

| Index | Value | Operation | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HPI1 | 0.9 | Sale | 01/2020 |
| HPI1 | 1.1 | Rent | 02/2020 |
| HPI2 | 0.89 | Sale | 01/2020 |
| HPI2 | 1.12 | Rent | 02/2020 |
| HPI3 | 0.85 | Sale | 01/2020 |
| HPI3 | 1.22 | Rent | 02/2020 |
| Median | 0.91 | Sale | 01/2020 |
| Median | 1.02 | Rent | 02/2020 |

I need to plot each HPI with the Median, by operation. this means I need three plots in one figure, the first one will be HPI1 + Median, the second would be HPI2 + Median, and the third one would be HPI3 + Median. I'm using ggplot with a loop, but I've only managed to do 1 plot with the four lines. I don't know how  to repeat the plot by  HPI but keeping Median. Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

I am currently using this code (RES is the data frame)

```
for(z in operation  
ggplot(RES[operation==z,],aes(x=interaction(month,year,sep = " "),y=Value,group=index),alpha=0.02) + geom_line(aes(linetype=index)) + geom_point() + scale_linetype_manual(values=c("dotted", "solid")) + theme(legend.position='bottom',legend.title=element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+ geom_hline(aes(yintercept=1,colour="red"),show.legend = F)+facet_wrap(~operacion,scales = "free",ncol = 2)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution.
It's scalable in case of many HPI.
It's fully based on `tidyverse`.
The idea is to set `Median` next to each `HPIn` by using two `pivot` commands from `tidyr`.
You can get multiple plots in one image with `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`.

SOLUTION

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)


df %>% 
 
 # transform in date
 mutate(Month = as.Date(paste0("01/", Month), format = "%d/%m/%Y")) %>% 
 
 # reshape data
 pivot_wider(names_from = Index, values_from = Value) %>% 
 pivot_longer(starts_with("HPI"), names_to = "Index", values_to = "Value") %>% 
 
 # plot by HPI
 ggplot(aes(x = Month)) +
 geom_line(aes(y = Value, colour = Index)) +
 geom_line(aes(y = Median, colour = "Median")) +
 geom_point(aes(y = Value, colour = Index)) +
 geom_point(aes(y = Median, colour = "Median")) +
 scale_x_date(date_labels = "%m %Y", date_breaks = "1 month") +
 facet_grid(Index~Operation)
```

[image]

The legend is redundant. If you don't want it: remove `color = "Median"` in the second `geom_line` and add `show.legend = FALSE` in the first `geom_line`.
Or you can add `+ theme(legend.position = "none")` at the end.

DATA

```r
# (I just tripled your data)
df <- tibble::tribble(
 ~Index,    ~Value, ~Operation, ~Month,
 "HPI1",    0.9,    "Sale", "01/2020",
 "HPI1",    1.1,    "Rent", "02/2020",
 "HPI2",    0.89,   "Sale", "01/2020",
 "HPI2",    1.12,   "Rent", "02/2020",
 "HPI3",    0.85,   "Sale", "01/2020",
 "HPI3",    1.22,   "Rent", "02/2020",
 "Median",  0.91,   "Sale", "01/2020",
 "Median",  1.02,   "Rent", "02/2020",
 "HPI1",    0.9,    "Sale", "02/2020",
 "HPI1",    1.1,    "Rent", "03/2020",
 "HPI2",    0.89,   "Sale", "02/2020",
 "HPI2",    1.12,   "Rent", "03/2020",
 "HPI3",    0.85,   "Sale", "02/2020",
 "HPI3",    1.22,   "Rent", "03/2020",
 "Median",  0.91,   "Sale", "02/2020",
 "Median",  1.02,   "Rent", "03/2020",
 "HPI1",    0.9,    "Sale", "03/2020",
 "HPI1",    1.1,    "Rent", "04/2020",
 "HPI2",    0.89,   "Sale", "03/2020",
 "HPI2",    1.12,   "Rent", "04/2020",
 "HPI3",    0.85,   "Sale", "03/2020",
 "HPI3",    1.22,   "Rent", "04/2020",
 "Median",  0.91,   "Sale", "03/2020",
 "Median",  1.02,   "Rent", "04/2020")
```

Comment: thank you very much for this answer! It looks very good. For some reason, I cant see the lines in my plot. I can only see the points.Do you have any idea of where this could be coming from?

Comment: Because in the data you showed you have only one point for each time series. I only doubled your data frame to show lines. I wrote it in the answer

Comment: actually: tripled your data!

Comment: Dear Edo, I'm moving forward with this but now I have three numeric columns more, with SD and upper and lower limits to plot the confidence interval. I have this numbers for the indices and NA for the median index (becuase I don't need it there).  But I can't get the reshaping to work. Do you know why? I was thinking on posting another question with the data but maybe you could know.  Thnx!!!

Comment: I think you should post a new question because it isn't related to this one. New data and a new example would be needed. Also, remember that every time you post a question, if you think you got the answer you were looking for, you should accept the answer. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.) out

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `foreach` loop

***Note: I used sample data provided in @Edo answer***

#### Initial library load & prepare the legend for later used

```
library(ggplot2) # For obvious reason - graph
library(dplyr) # For manipulate data a bit
library(foreach) # Foreach Loop
library(cowplot) # For manipulate graphs

# Define the line type Solid for variables and dotted line for Median
line_type <- c("solid", "1111")
names(line_type) <- c("Index (HPI1, HPI2, HPI3)", "Median")

# Generate dummy plot just to extract legend
plot_for_legend <- ggplot(data = RES %>%
    mutate(Index = if_else(Index == "Median", "Median",
  # If you have more Index than HPI1, HPI2, HPI3, can just simply remove
  # the text in parentheses and leave it as Index - make sure you change
  # the line_type variable accordingly and adjust all the places needed.
                           "Index (HPI1, HPI2, HPI3)")),
  aes(x = Month, y = Value, group = Index)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Index)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = line_type) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom', legend.title = element_blank(),
  axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
# Extracting legend using get_legend from cowplot package
legend_area <- get_legend(plot_for_legend)
```

#### Using foreach loop to iterate through each operation and graph them

```
operation <- unique(RES[["Operation"]])  
operation_plot <- foreach(z = operation) %do% {
  # filter data to current operation Rent/ Sale
  operation_data <- RES %>% filter(Operation == z)
  median_data <- operation_data %>% filter(Index == "Median")
  
  median_line_point <- geom_line(data = median_data,
    aes(x = Month, y = Value, group = Index, linetype = "Median"), 
    alpha=1)
  median_point <- geom_point(data = median_data,
    aes(x = Month, y = Value))
  
  list_index <- unique(operation_data[["Index"]])
  list_index <- list_index[list_index != "Median"]
  
  list_plot <- foreach(i_index = list_index) %do% {
    ggplot(data = operation_data %>% filter(Index == i_index),
      aes(x = Month, y = Value, group = Index, 
          # in case you change the line_type make sure to change the name 
          # here accordingly
          linetype ="Index (HPI1, HPI2, HPI3)"), 
      alpha=1) +
      geom_line(linetype = "solid") +
      geom_point() +
      median_line_point + median_point +
      scale_linetype_manual(values = line_type) +
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1,colour = "red"), show.legend = F) +
      ylab(i_index) + 
      theme(legend.position = "none")
  }
  # put all the plot in the list into one
  current_plot <- plot_grid(plotlist = list_plot, ncol = 2)

  # Generate title for operation
  title <- ggdraw() + 
    draw_label(
      sprintf("%s operation", z),
      fontface = 'bold',
      x = 0,
      hjust = 0
    ) +
    theme(
      # add margin on the left of the drawing canvas,
      # so title is aligned with left edge of first plot
      plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 7)
    )

  # Combine title, main plot & legend into one
  current_plot_w_legend <- plot_grid(title, current_plot, legend_area, nrow = 3, rel_heights = c(.5, 10, 1))
}
# Set names of the plot variables for easier access
names(operation_plot) <- operation
```

With some sample data here is the output

[image: Sales operation]

[image: Rent operation]

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It is working for me. The only thing I'm missing is the legend indicating what every type of line mean. ¿Do you know how to do that? Thanks!!!!

Comment: Updated the answer to do what you asking. Here only do t he linetype as they already on separate plot with different `y_axis` labels so I would just create legend for differentiate the `Median` and other `Index` lines